# Splitting name/value pairs with regex to ignore special characters based on surrounding characters

Tags: regex

I have this regex that's worked well so far that splits 'name=value' pairs separated by a given character.

```
(?s)([^\s=]+)=(.*?)(?=\s+[^\s=]+=|\Z)
```

I know the separator, but the problem is in the example below (tab separated):

```
usrName=Wilma   sev=4   cat=Detection   CommandLine="C:\powershell.exe" -Enc 0ATQBpAG0AAcABDAHIAZQBkAHMAIgA=    IOCValue=   ProcessEndTime=2023-01-18 15:51:05
```

https://regex101.com/r/1wgVxs/5

Some values can have no value in the case of 'IOCValue' which works as expected, however some values like the CommandLine are giving me up to -Enc as one match and the remainder to the next pair as another.

What I'm hoping to get out from the above is:

```
usrName=Wilma
sev=4   
cat=Detection   
CommandLine="C:\powershell.exe" -Enc 0ATQBpAG0AAcABDAHIAZQBkAHMAIgA=    
IOCValue=   
ProcessEndTime=2023-01-18 15:51:05
```

But I'm getting:

```
usrName=Wilma
sev=4   
cat=Detection   
CommandLine="C:\powershell.exe" -Enc 
0ATQBpAG0AAcABDAHIAZQBkAHMAIgA= 
IOCValue=   
ProcessEndTime=2023-01-18 15:51:05
```

Given I know the separator is a tab I think what I need is to only look for name=value pairs when they are at the start of the line or proceeded by the separator (tab). Is this possible?

Note, I can expect a space separator too, but I have a less performant and messy non-regex version I can send these too, so presume tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this simplified regex:

```bash
(?s)([^\s=]+)=(.*?)(?=\t|\Z)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1wgVxs/6)

Here, lookahead `(?=\t|\Z)` will make sure that value part is followed by either a tab character or end position.

Comment: Thanks. I've been staring at this for ages, and you've made it shorter too :) 

To be honest this comes in as a log file and some might be space separated so I believe there is nothing that can be done in this case do you think?

Comment: Yeah that would be impossible to parse if values can contain space and `=` and there are no consistent delimiters between key-value pairs.